# google chart extra customization

Tags: asp.net, google-visualization

I am using Google chart's stacked bar chart.I did many customization to achieve my functionality.
1. the value present inside each bar chart must be in center 
2. The total of each each inside value should come at the end of each bar

Please find my below Google chart example

```
<pre><html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var wrapper;
    function drawVisualization() {

        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'department');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Draft');
        data.addColumn('number', 'InProgress');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Completed');

        data.addRows([
            ['IT', {v:18, f:'18%'}, {v:40, f:'40%'}, {v:42, f:'42%'}],
            ['Administrative', {v:40, f:'40%'}, {v:30, f:'30%'}, {v:30, f:'30%'}],
            ['Sales', {v:35, f:'35%'}, {v:10, f:'10%'}, {v:55, f:'55%'}],
            ['Sales', {v:15.5, f:'15.5%'}, {v:65, f:'65%'}, {v:19.5, f:'19.5%'}]
            /*
            ['Administrative', 40, 30, 30],
            ['Sale', 35, 10, 55],
            ['Accounts', 10, 80, 10]
            */
        ]); 


        //wrapper for graph
        wrapper = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));

        //attach event listeners
        google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper, 'select', onSelectHandler);

        /*
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
          {negativeColor: 'red', suffix : "%"});
        formatter.format(data, 2);
        */

        //add view for data
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 
                        1, {
                            calc: "stringify",
                            sourceColumn: 1,
                            type: "string",
                            role: "annotation"
                        }, 2, {
                            calc: "stringify",
                            sourceColumn: 2,
                            type: "string",
                            role: "annotation"
                        }, 3, {
                            calc: "stringify",
                            sourceColumn: 3,
                            type: "string",
                            role: "annotation",
                        }
                        ]);

        //set options for graph
        var options = {
            title:"Objective status report",
            isStacked: true,

            width:1000, height:400,
            vAxis: {title: ""},
            hAxis: {title: ""},

            //hide tool tip
            'tooltip' : {
              trigger: 'none'
            },


            hAxis: {
                viewWindow: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100
                },
                ticks: [{v:0, f:'0%'},{v:10, f:'10%'},{v:20, f:'20%'},{v:30, f:'30%'},
                        {v:40, f:'40%'}, {v:50, f:'50%'}, {v:60, f:'60%'}, {v:70, f:'70%'},
                        {v:80, f:'80%'}, {v:90, f:'90%'}, {v:100, f:'100%'}]

            },

            //set colour for series
            series: [{color: '#F66E25', visibleInLegend: true}, { color : '#2579F6', visibleInLegend: true}, {color: '#9946F7', visibleInLegend: true}]
        };      

        //draw graph
        wrapper.draw(view, options);


        function onSelectHandler(){
            alert("hi there");
        }


    }

    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="visualization"></div>
  </body>
</html></pre>
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: ok , what i want to do is .. whn you run this example in html. You will c ,each bar is divided into three sections , and for each section i am displaying certain percentage value inside that bar.

I want that value to be come in the middle of the part.
(18% ,40% , 42 % ) should come in middle.same for other bars 

and also the total calculation of the above mentioned percetage should be displyed at the end of each bar